# Google maps API - Adding all locations for a company, rather than each location individually

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to create a Google map for a company's website that lists all of the stores that stock their products. These are mostly department stores, supermarket chains, etc.

Aside from individually adding every single location, is there a way I can add all of the locations for a given company to a Google map?

Like if I wanted to list all of Kmart, Target, and Walmart's locations on a single map, which users could filter and search, is there a simple way to do this?

It's worth noting it would also need to be accurate, so by adding Target, I wouldn't want it to also include "John's target shooting range" for example.

Any suggestions anyone can provide would be greatly appreciated. Even if it's just to confirm that this isn't possible.

Comment: Why is this getting downvoted?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the google maps' javascript places to do the job. You can use, for example, nearby search witch return you all market near you. Then, you can specified some names, type of shops, if they are open now...

This is a simply nearby search:

```
var request = {
location: pyrmont,
radius: '500',
types: ['store']
};

service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
service.nearbySearch(request, callback);
```

[This](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/place-search?hl=fr) is an example of nearby search provided by google.

You also can add the name of the place (the system return you some places with the name that you precise):

```
var request = {
location: pyrmont,
radius: '500',
types: ['store'],
name: 'Zara'
};

service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
service.nearbySearch(request, callback);
```

However, and as you can see, this solution do not resolve all your problem, you can not find all the shop of a company. You just can find shops around you (or any places).

You may consult the [google's documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places?hl=en#place_search_requests).

*Tell me if you have some questions.*

Comment: Thanks for the reply. In researching this I had a quick read through the Google Maps documentation, but I couldn't find anything relevant. I was really just hoping someone with more experience might know something I dont.